# SFDX: Authorize a Dev Hub command

Tags: salesforcedx, salesforcedx-cli, vs-code

I get "sfdx force:auth:web:login --setdefaultdevhubusername ended with exit code 1"

[image]

[image]

Comment: Did you authorize the CLI to work with your DevHub?

Comment: We would need to see the logs from that period in time. You can find it in `.sfdx/sfdx.log` (found in `~` in Linux/Unix/Mac or `%homepath%` in Windows). That should explain what happened.

Comment: @sfdcfox logs are comming blank.

Comment: @NavalSharma No This is what this step does.

Comment: @sfdcfox I got it working by giving the .sfdx as WR permission , Was is necessary ?

Comment: @VishalSharma If I understand your statement correctly, yes, you needed to have permissions in the dev hub org before you could do anything with it.

Comment: @sfdcfox By Permissions in Dev Hub means Enabling dev hub in my dev sandbox ?

Comment: @VishalSharma Yes, you can't connect as a dev hub to a non-dev-hub-enabled org, so you would have needed to enable it first.

Comment: @sfdcfox  I have already done this part.Its still not working.
If i give RWEX(777) Permission to .sfdx in ~ ,Then the Auth a dev hub runs and web page opens up to fill in credentials.But when i fill the creds and submit error is thrown at Salesforce CLI output stating that key.json should be 600 Octal as Permission Set (RW and not ex),And When i give that permission set , the auth a dev hub does not execute stating permission set error. 
I am using Ubuntu and i need to run vscode as SU to run the SFDX cmds else permsion er.
I am doing lightning web component trail